# How to disable / modify a button using SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to create a POC using SwiftUI and CoreML. I use a simple button to call some function (called `test` here). This function is pretty heavy as it performs a CoreML inference, and it can take up to a minute to compute.

I have several problems:

- The button is still active even when the computation is ongoing. In other words, if I click the button several times before the processing of the first click is finished, the processing will be performed several times. I want to disable the button as long as the processing is ongoing.
- I tried to modify the button's appearance to signify the user that the processing is ongoing. In the example bellow, I change the button color to red before calling the `test` function, and I change it back to blue when the processing is over. But it doesn't work.

In the code bellow, the `test` function is just sleeping for 5 seconds to simulate the CoreML inference.

```swift
func test() -> Void {
    print("Start processing")
    sleep(5)
    print("End processing")
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var buttonColor : Color = .blue

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Button(action: {
                self.buttonColor = .red
                test()
                self.buttonColor = .blue
            }) {
                Text("Start")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .background(self.buttonColor)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this problem is very straight forward for most of you. I just can't find the correct search keywords to solve it by myself. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is possible approach (see also comments in code). Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var buttonColor : Color = .blue

    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Button(action: {
                self.buttonColor = .red

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { // do in background
                    test()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.buttonColor = .blue // work with UI only in main
                    }
                }

            }) {
                Text("Start")
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .background(self.buttonColor)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .disabled(self.buttonColor == .red) // disabled while calculating
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer unblocked me. `DispatchQueue` was the keyword I was looking for. Thanks for your help.